# Update all quote items with qty 1 in magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, quote, quoteitem

I am trying to update all the quote item qty as soon as we navigated to the cart page.

by using below code.

```
$quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
$quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
                foreach($quoteItems as $item) {
                        $productSku = $item->getSku();
                        $item->setQty(1);
                        $item->save();
                }
```

The above code working fine if we run from the script for or from any of the controller file.

I am looking for code to implement in event and observers,

Is there any event for this, once navigated to cart page i need update qty for each item as 1.

Can anyone suggest which event is worth for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Controller dispatch event of 
 Cart page `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index`.

On this event fire an observer and update the Cart Qty.

### Observer

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer\CheckoutCart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class UpdateQty implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
 {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;
    /**
     * @var CheckoutSession
     */
    private $checkoutSession;
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
     \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
     CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
     \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository

    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $this->logger->debug(__METHOD__);
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        if(!count($quoteItems) <= 0){
            return  $this;
        }
        try {

            foreach($quoteItems as $item) {
                    $productSku = $item->getSku();
                    $item->setQty(1);
                    $item->save();
            }
           $this->quoteRepository->save($quote); 
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: hi @Amit, Thanks, the event is fired, i have used below code to set the custom price of each item, 
$customPrice = 50;
$item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
     $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
     
     $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);, is this fine?

Comment: can you confirm me please?

Comment: You can do but it is very bad idea to change the price  at  cart page  using  event.  Best idea add an intermediate controller and  impment this logic

Comment: intermediate controller means, how you are saying? any suggestions?

Comment: intermedia  controller  means hitting an intermediate URL before  goto  cart page

Comment: will you help me to implement that one pls, i have no idea on that